# Escape powershell Variable in HTML

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to write a report in powershell and then sent the output to an HTML Page. i am figuring out how can i format my variable from my powershell script to HTML.
If i get an output which is not correct, i will it to have a blue font in my html page.

Here is my powershell script

```
$os =  (get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem).caption


function checkosvers {
if($os -contains "*Server*" ){
write-output "This is a server"}

else{
write-output "Its a $os"}
}

$osvers = checkosvers | foreach {$PSItem -replace ("Its a $os","<font  color='blue'>Its a $os</font>")}
$osvers | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -as List  | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\XX\Desktop\mypage.html"
```

if i put a string in place of a varible, it appears blue in my html page
{$PSItem -replace ("Its a $os","Its a $os")}

Comment: Call your function before the HTML and set the result you want into a variable. Then in the HTML, you can interpolate the value as `$($os)` within your desired HTML tag(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a filter of it, and just have it output what you want. I would have it accept values from the pipeline for ease of use, so something like this:

```
filter checkosvers {
param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$osVer)
if($osVer -match "Server" ){
    "This is a server"
}else{
    "<font color='blue'>Its a $osVer</font>"}
}
```

Then you can just pipe things to it like:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> 'Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter'|checkosvers
This is a server
```

or...

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem).caption|checkosvers
<font color='blue'>Its a Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise</font>
```